# How do i change the link for the “My Cart(1 item)” and make it state just the number not the word “item” like so, “My Cart(1)”?

Tags: magento

I don't want to change it in file lang app\locale\en_Us\Mage_Checkout.csv. How should i go for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a custom translation file:

```
//In app/design/frontend/your/theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv:

"My Cart (%s item)","My Cart (%s)"
"My Cart (%s items)","My Cart (%s)"
```

Answer (score 0):

either go for it, use inline translation tool or the best way would be to copy the same file to your theme folder and edit there

```
app/design/frontend/your/theme/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv
```

Comment: I dont want to touch the translation file.

Comment: use inline translation tool then

Answer (score 0):

You can go to /var/www/testmagento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php and change the
"My Cart..." message occuring in 48,50,52 of addCartLink() to desired format.

As per the Ben's comment, I have `edited the solution from above to the below one`.

Magento gives priority to local files then the core. So, i can take advantage of this.

Create the necessary files under local folder as req by 
/var/www/testmagento/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php.

Copy paste the Links.php from /var/www/testmagento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/to /var/www/testmagento/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/

Change the "My Cart..." message occuring in 48,50,52 of addCartLink() to desired format.

Comment: Do not modify core, ever. Use a rewrite, unless you are translating strings as is the case here.